# AzureServiceTokenProviderException using key vault

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-keyvault

I don't know what is wrong, anyone got any ideas? I just followed this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/azure/key-vault/vs-key-vault-add-connected-service#feedback

This error only happens when the website gets published to Azure.

````
AzureServiceTokenProviderException: Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://vault.azure.net, Authority: https://login.windows.net/1855fd54-8283-4d57-ab22-4e818e22fcf7. Exception Message: Tried the following 3 methods to get an access token, but none of them worked.
Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://vault.azure.net, Authority: https://login.windows.net/1855fd54-8283-4d57-ab22-4e818e22fcf7. Exception Message: Tried to get token using Managed Service Identity. Access token could not be acquired. An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://vault.azure.net, Authority: https://login.windows.net/1855fd54-8283-4d57-ab22-4e818e22fcf7. Exception Message: Tried to get token using Visual Studio. Access token could not be acquired. Visual Studio Token provider file not found at "D:\local\LocalAppData\.IdentityService\AzureServiceAuth\tokenprovider.json"
Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://vault.azure.net, Authority: https://login.windows.net/1855fd54-8283-4d57-ab22-4e818e22fcf7. Exception Message: Tried to get token using Azure CLI. Access token could not be acquired. 'az' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.AzureServiceTokenProvider.GetAuthResultAsyncImpl(string resource, string authority, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

AzureServiceTokenProviderException: Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://vault.azure.net, Authority: https://login.windows.net/1855fd54-8283-4d57-ab22-4e818e22fcf7. Exception Message: Tried the following 3 methods to get an access token, but none of them worked. Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://vault.azure.net, Authority: https://login.windows.net/1855fd54-8283-4d57-ab22-4e818e22fcf7. Exception Message: Tried to get token using Managed Service Identity. Access token could not be acquired. An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions. Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://vault.azure.net, Authority: https://login.windows.net/1855fd54-8283-4d57-ab22-4e818e22fcf7. Exception Message: Tried to get token using Visual Studio. Access token could not be acquired. Visual Studio Token provider file not found at "D:\local\LocalAppData\.IdentityService\AzureServiceAuth\tokenprovider.json" Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://vault.azure.net, Authority: https://login.windows.net/1855fd54-8283-4d57-ab22-4e818e22fcf7. Exception Message: Tried to get token using Azure CLI. Access token could not be acquired. 'az' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.AzureServiceTokenProvider.GetAuthResultAsyncImpl(string resource, string authority, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.AzureServiceTokenProvider.<get_KeyVaultTokenCallback>b__8_0(string authority, string resource, string scope)
FindEnBar.Program+<>c__DisplayClass2_0+<<SetupConfiguration>g__GetToken|0>d.MoveNext() in Program.cs
Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultCredential.PostAuthenticate(HttpResponseMessage response)
Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultCredential.ProcessHttpRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClient.GetSecretsWithHttpMessagesAsync(string vaultBaseUrl, Nullable<int> maxresults, Dictionary<string, List<string>> customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClientExtensions.GetSecretsAsync(IKeyVaultClient operations, string vaultBaseUrl, Nullable<int> maxresults, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault.AzureKeyVaultConfigurationProvider.LoadAsync()
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault.AzureKeyVaultConfigurationProvider.Load()
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationRoot..ctor(IList<IConfigurationProvider> providers)
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.BuildAppConfiguration()
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()```
````

Answer (score 0):

I got something similar after changing my acount password. After logging out and back in again in VS2019 or VS2022, the exception went away.

Answer (score -3):

In the tutorial, it uses [Azure Managed Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview) to access Key Vault.

See the following code:

```
     public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((ctx, builder) =>
            {
                var keyVaultEndpoint = GetKeyVaultEndpoint();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyVaultEndpoint))
                {
                    var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
                    var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(
                        new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(
                            azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
                    builder.AddAzureKeyVault(
                        keyVaultEndpoint, keyVaultClient, new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager());
                }
            }
         ).UseStartup<Startup>();
```

In your local development, it will use the user credential of VS or use the credential stored by Azure CLI.

However, in the cloud, you need to turn on the identity of your [VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/qs-configure-portal-windows-vm) or [Web App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=dotnet#adding-a-system-assigned-identity). And then [add access policy for that identity in Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/managed-identity#grant-your-app-access-to-key-vault).

Then, your code would be able to use Key Vault without any problem.